Understanding symmetry of the definition of exponential graph $H^G$
I am reading Hom complexes and homotopy theory in the category of graphs and am trying to understand the definition of an exponential graph for simple, undirected graphs (with loops allowed).
Definition: For graphs $G$ and $H$, the categorical exponential graph $H^G$ is a graph with vertex set $\{ f: V(G) \rightarrow V(H) \}$, the collection of all vertex set maps, with adjacency given by $f \sim f'$ if whenever $v \sim v'$ in $G$, we have $f(v) \sim f'(v')$ in $H$.
He goes on to give an example where

$G$ is defined via $V(G) = \{0, 1\}$ and $E(G) = \{(0,0), (0,1)\}$
$H$ is defined via $V(H) = \{A, B, C \}$ and $E(H) = \{(A,A), (A,B), (B,C)\}$.

Note that we are in the setting of undirected graphs, and that I omitted redundant edges like $(1,0) \in E(G)$. However, the definition above does not look symmetric to me in the sense that $v \sim v'$ could imply that $f(v) \sim f'(v')$ but not $f'(v) \sim f(v')$.
This happens to be the case in the example above for the two functions $f(0) = A$, $f(1) = B$ and $f'(0) = B$, $f'(1) = A$. Indeed, we have $0 \sim 0$ and $0 \sim 1$ and thus
$$ f(0) = A \sim B = f'(0) \quad \text{and} \quad f(0) = A \sim A = f'(1) \, ,$$
but
$$ f'(0) = B \nsim B = f(1) \, .$$
In the example of the paper, the author did not connect these two functions which makes me wonder if the definition should be understood to hold in both directions, if there is a mistake in the example of the paper, or if I am missing something else here.
Searching around on the internet I keep finding a similar definition as the one above with no obvious way of resolving how to symmetrize this definition (i.e. is it enough if it holds for one direction or does it have to hold for both?).
Does anyone have a reference to an established, unambiguous definition of a graph exponential in this setting or have experience of how these things are usually understood?

If $v \sim v'$ then also $v' \sim v$, hence $f(v') \sim f'(v)$, hence $f'(v) \sim f(v')$, so the exponential graph is symmetric. In your example, $f \nsim f'$ because $1 \sim 0$ but $f(1) \nsim f'(0)$.
